# With Python NLTK, is there a stemmer that distinguishes unknown words?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm stemming documents and need to separate words that have stems from those that do not.  The NLTK stemming methods all return the input for words that have no stem.

> > > stemmer.stem('running')      # word has a stem
> > >       run
> > >       stemmer.stem('run')            # word stem is the word itself
> > >       run
> > >       stemmer.stem('asdf')          # word is nonsense
> > >       asdf

I need way to distinguish the latter case.  Is there a stemmer that returns two results (stem and found indicator) or a valid stem list?

Comment: You might have a lemmatiser in mind. A stemmer only has a very small vocabulary (for irregular words), otherwise all words are unknown and are treated according to their shape (the ending, mostly). The stemmer returns "asdf" not because it thinks it's non-sense, but because there is no rule that says to cut off the suffix "-f".

Comment: Why do you think it should be the stemmer's job to tell you if the base is a real word? Lemmatize and look up the result in a large wordlist, or use a spell checker.